# The structure for mathstyle in even and odd pages

Tags: math-mode, double-sided, page

I want to have the following structure:

```
ifoddpage\everydisplay{\color{blue}
ifevenpage\everydisplay{\color{red}}
```

I made the below command:

```
\newcommand{\ctt}{\checkoddpage
\ifoddpage\everydisplay{\color{blue}}
\else\everydisplay{\color{red}}
\fi}
```

This structure does not work correctly. I use `xelatex` compiler.
How can i do this?
This is my codes:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{everysel}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{changepage}
\newcommand{\ctt}{\checkoddpage
\ifoddpage\everydisplay{\color{blue}}
\else\everydisplay{\color{red}}
\fi}\ctt
\begin{document}
\[a^2=b^2+c^2\]
text\newpage%\ctt
\[a^3=b^3+c^3\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: When I try your mwe (with `\ctt` uncommented) the command seems to work, i.e., the equation on the first page is blue and the equation on the second page is red. Do you get any error message? If not, what does the output look like?

Comment: Thanks @ Marijn. I don't want use \ctt  for every page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would move the check directly into `\everydisplay`

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{changepage}

\newcommand*{\ctt}{\checkoddpage\ifoddpage\color{blue}\else\color{red}\fi}

\everydisplay\expandafter{\the\everydisplay\ctt}

\begin{document}
Bla bla
\[a^2=b^2+c^2\] % will be blue
text
\newpage
Bla bla
\[a^2=b^2+c^2\] % will be red
text
\newpage
Bla bla
\[a^2=b^2+c^2\] % will be blue
text
\newpage
\renewcommand*{\ctt}{\relax}% revert to do nothing
Bla bla
\[a^2=b^2+c^2\] % will be black
text

\end{document}
```